# Bug: adding new contact through relationship limited to subtype

Tags: relationships, contact-types

I have a custom relationship type that is has contact B limited to a contact sub-type. Now when I go to a contact to create add this custom relationship and use as related contact ***New individual*** create a new relationship for this custom relationship, then it always fails with the error message:

> 1 invalid relationship record 1 relationship record was not created
>   due to an invalid contact type.

I think this is a bug. When you use ***New individual*** from the context of a relationship that needs a particular sub-type, then you would expect that the new individual is automatically created with that sub-type. Otherwise the convenience of on-the-fly creation has become useless.

I have been able to reproduce this error on the demo site.

Can someone confirm this?

Answer (score 3):

I just replicated this.

First, let's discuss the workaround:  Go to **Administer menu > Customize Data and Screens > Profiles**.  Click on "Reserved Profiles" and edit the "New Individual" profile.  Add the "contact subtype" field and save.  Now, when creating on-the-fly individuals, you can select their contact subtype.  I tested and confirmed that this works.

As for the original problem, I agree that this should probably be considered a bug.  However, given that this is a relatively infrequently-used workflow with an easy workaround, I doubt the core team will be investing resources into its fix.  I'm sure they'd welcome a patch though.

Comment: The work around is useful when the user knows what sub-type is expected, but initially he doesn't and the system is not helpful. This basically defeats the whole purpose of ***New Individual*** to quickly add a correct user, without leaving the context. 

When an ignorant user without previous concept of work flow conventions sees a useful inviting link, then it should simply work.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently an issue open for this: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15704

As Jon said, it is non-critical so the core team is not currently working on it. If anyone is able to step up to provide funding or a patch it would be most welcome.

Comment: Could you give me an estimate of the necessary funding for this?

Comment: Roughly I'd guess a simple fix (option a) might be in the $500 range. Prices and info are here: https://civicrm.org/paid-issue-queue - you can submit the form to get a formal estimate.